# Does a line integral depend continiously on the curve?

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $\gamma_n: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ be a family of curves which converges uniformly to the curve $\gamma$. Does the line integral $\int_{\gamma_n} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d}s$ over an arbitrary vector field $\vec{F}(x,y)$ converges to $\int_{\gamma} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d}s$? In particular, I'm interested in the case of a closed curve.

---

Attempts of a solution/remarks:

- If the derivative of $\gamma_n$ also converges uniformly to the derivative of $\gamma$, then convergence of the integrals follows from the expression $\int_{\gamma_n} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{d}s = \int_0^1 \vec{F}(\gamma_n(t)) \cdot \dot{\gamma}_n(t) dt$.
- So for a counterexample a uniform convergent family of curves with not-uniform convergent derivative is needed. However all my attempts using some variation of the standard example $n \sin(x/n)$ were unsuccessful - mainly because the discontinuity of $\vec{F}(\gamma_n(t)) \cdot \dot{\gamma}_n(t)$ vanished after integration.
- If the curves are simple (no self-intersections) and closed, then one can appeal to the Stokes Theorem to rewrite the integrals into integrals over surfaces. These integrals intuitively converge to zero if the surfaces become smaller and smaller. This is however not a proof... (and does not say anything about the case of self-intersecting curves)

Comment: If you choose arc-length parametrization of the curves, I think their derivatives must converge uniformly too. Since the integral is independent of parametrization, you're done.

Comment: Good idea! However, for this to work the reparametrization $s_n(t) = \int_{t_0}^t |\dot\gamma_n(\tau)| d\tau$ has to depend uniformly on $n$ (otherwise the reparametrized curve $\tilde\gamma_n(s) = \gamma_n(t(s))$ is no longer uniform convergent). Although this simplified the question, I cant see why this should hold true in general.

Answer (score 1):

While this is likely not relevant to OP anymore, the same question has been asked multiple more times since, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208938/topology-of-line-integral-convergence-on-the-space-of-curves), without resolution, though it has been observed that length seems to play a role, such as [in this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575795/does-uniform-convergence-of-curves-imply-convergence-of-integrals/2577045#2577045). So here is a complete proof for reference.

For concreteness, integrals are taken to be complex line integrals, but this works in any finite dimension.

> **Theorem**. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open, $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ continuous, and let $\gamma_n: [0, 1] \to U$ be continuous curves such that $\gamma_n \rightarrow \gamma_0$ uniformly and $\sup_{n \in \{0, 1, ...\}} L(\gamma_n) = K < \infty$. Then $$\int_{\gamma_n} f(z) \rightarrow \int_{\gamma_0} f(z).$$

Before we begin the proof, let us describe the definition of line integrals employed. Please excuse the slightly non-standard notation. In any finite $\mathfrak{Z} \subseteq [0, 1)$, any element $t$ has a successor $t'$, which is the next-largest element (or $1$ if $t = \max \mathfrak{Z}$). We assume for convenience that $0 \in \mathfrak{Z}$. Then $|\mathfrak{Z}| = \max_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} t' - t$ is the **fineness** of $\mathfrak{Z}$. If then $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is open, $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ is any function, and $\gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous curve, we can define the **Riemann sum** $\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t))(\gamma(t') - \gamma(t))$ (depending on $f, \gamma, \mathfrak{Z}$). When there is a complex number $I$ such that $|\mathfrak{Z}_n| \to 0$ for a sequence $(\mathfrak{Z}_n)$ of finite sets as above always yields that the sequence of Riemann sums converges to $I$, then we say $f$ is Riemann-integrable along $\gamma$, and $I$ is the **integral**. We then write $\int_\gamma f(z) \mathrm{d} z$ or just $\int_\gamma f$ for $I$. The **length** of $\gamma$, $L(\gamma)$, is similarly defined as the limit of sums of the form $\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} |\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)|$, if it exists.

The paragraphs are in order of decreasing conceptual importance. This is because while the proof may seem long and technical, we will see that it comes about naturally if we start at the right place with some intuition. If you want a more standard write-up, you can just start by reading (3).

(1) The main idea to control the terms is to replace $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_n$ with polygonal approximations $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_n$. Considering the difference $\int_{\Gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f$, we can then split up each of the integrals into the integrals over the individual segments. This works particularly well if the polygonal approximations use the same base points. So we have some finite set $\mathfrak{Z} \subseteq [0, 1)$ with $0 \in \mathfrak{Z}$, in which the successor notation applies. Then $\Gamma_i$ is the line from $\gamma_i(t)$ to $\gamma_i(t')$ on the interval $[t, t']$, for $i \in \{0, n\}$. Denoting the segment from $t$ to $t'$ with $\Gamma_i[t, t']$, this allows us to write $$\int_{\Gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f = \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f - \int_{\Gamma_n[t, t']} f.$$
On the segments $\Gamma_0[t, t']$ and $\Gamma_n[t, t']$, $f$ should behave very similarly, because these segments are so close together. To formalise this, we can consider the affine transformation $z \mapsto a_t z + b_t$ which maps $\Gamma_0[t, t']$ to $\Gamma_n[t, t']$, i.e. $\gamma_0(t)$ to $\gamma_n(t)$ and $\gamma_0(t')$ to $\gamma_n(t')$. Then $\int_{\Gamma_n[t, t']} f = \int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(a_t z + b) a_t \mathrm{d} z$. Hence
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \left|{\int_{\Gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f} \right| 
    &= \left|{ \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f - \int_{\Gamma_n[t, t']} f}\right| \\
    &= \left|{ \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(z) \mathrm{d} z - \int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(a_t z + b_t) a_t \mathrm{d} z } \right| \\
    &\leq \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|{\int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(z) - f(a_t z + b_t) a_t \mathrm{d} z } \right| \\
    &\leq \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|{\int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(z) - f(a_t z + b_t) \mathrm{d} z }\right| + \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|{\int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(a_t z + b_t) (a_t - 1) \mathrm{d} z } \right|.
    \end{aligned}
$$
The first summand is easily controlled, as we can rewrite it as $$\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|{\frac{\gamma_0(t') - \gamma_0(t)}{t'-t}\int_{t}^{t'} f(\Gamma_0(s)) - f(\Gamma_n(s)) \mathrm{d} s }\right|,$$ which is at most $\epsilon L(\gamma_0)$ if we make it so that $f$ actually differs only by $\epsilon$ for close inputs. Indeed, $$|\Gamma_0(s) - \Gamma_n(s)| \leq \max\{|\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_n(t)|, |\gamma_0(t') - \gamma_n(t')|\}$$ for all $s \in [t, t']$, so we can invoke uniform convergence, say making $|\gamma_0(s) - \gamma_n(s)| < \delta$ for all $s \in [0, 1]$, and use uniform continuity of $f$ to choose $\delta$.

For the second summand, it appears we would have to control $|a_t - 1|$. Indeed, if this was at most $\epsilon$ and $f$ is bounded by $M$, then $$\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|{\int_{\Gamma_0[t, t']} f(a_t z + b_t) (a_t - 1) \mathrm{d} z } \right| \leq \epsilon M L(\Gamma_0).$$ To bound $a_t$, note that $$a_t - 1 = \frac{(\gamma_n(t') - \gamma_0(t')) - (\gamma_n(t) - \gamma_0(t))}{\gamma_0(t') - \gamma_0(t)}.$$ The numerator is bounded above by $2 \delta$, and the denominator is bounded below by $\beta = \min_{t} |\gamma_0(t') - \gamma_0(t)|$. So to make $|a_t - 1| < \epsilon$, we need to choose $\delta$ much smaller than $\beta$. This would seem to pose a significant challenge, because $\beta$ depends on $\mathfrak{Z}$. As $n$ depends on $\delta$, this means that $\mathfrak{Z}$ must be chosen independent of $n$. In the next step, this will require us to argue a kind of "uniform integrability". Fortunately this is not difficult at all (and indeed a rather standard argument), and the proof goes through without issues from here. By extension, this also means that $\delta$ will not just be chosen to make $|f(\Gamma_0(s)) - f(\Gamma_n(s))|$ small, but rather this will be ensured by another appropriate constant $\rho$, and we then set $\delta =\min\{\rho, \epsilon \beta\}$.

(2) In the end, our argument will be that
$$
\left|\int_{\gamma_0} f - \int_{\gamma_n} f\right|
    \leq \left|\int_{\gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_0} f\right| + \left|\int_{\Gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f\right| + \left|\int_{\gamma_n} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f\right|,$$
and that every summand on the right goes to zero. We have treated the middle term in (1), so let us see how to treat the first and third term. As these have the same form, they are analogous, so we suppress the index in notation. First, we divide the term further like this:
$$
    \left|{\int_{\gamma} f - \int_{\Gamma} f} \right| \leq \left|{\int_{\gamma} f - \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t))}\right| + \left|{\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)) - \int_{\Gamma} f}\right|.
$$
The first summand here is the "uniform integrability" alluded to before: We have to ensure that $\mathfrak{Z}$ is fine enough to approximate the integral well, without having much control over $\mathfrak{Z}$. Certainly we can choose *some* refinement $\mathfrak{Z}'$ of $\mathfrak{Z}$ with which the integral is approximated well, say to at most $\epsilon$. So the question is on the difference of the two Riemann sums defined with $\mathfrak{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{Z}'$ respectively. To deal with this difference, we note that for all $t \in \mathfrak{Z}'$ there is the next-closest element $t_{\mathfrak{Z}} \in \mathfrak{Z}$, which allows us to use a telescoping trick:
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \left|\int_{\gamma} f - \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t))\right|
    &\leq \epsilon + \left|\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}'} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)) - \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t))\right| \\
    &= \epsilon + \left|\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}'} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)) - \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}'} f(\gamma(t_{\mathfrak{Z}})) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t))\right| \\
    &\leq \epsilon + \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}'} \left|f(\gamma(t)) - f(\gamma(t_{\mathfrak{Z}})) \right| \left|\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)\right| \\
    &\leq \epsilon + \epsilon L(\gamma)
    \leq \epsilon(1+K).
    \end{aligned}
$$
(Note that between some of these sums, $t'$ has different meanings, as it either refers to the successor in $\mathfrak{Z}$ or in $\mathfrak{Z}'$.) We use here that $\mathfrak{Z}$ is at least so fine that uniform continuity of $f$ can be invoked, i.e. we ensure that when $|s-t| < \max_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} t' - t$, then $|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)| < \rho$. To do this, we will need uniform equicontinuity of the sequence $(\gamma_n)$, but that is no problem because it converges uniformly.
The second and final summand is then the easiest, as this is just the statement that the integral is approximated well with a polygonal interpolation, a central lemma in complex analysis:
$$
    \begin{aligned}
    \left|\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)) - \int_{\Gamma} f \right| 
    &= \left|\sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} f(\gamma(t)) (\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)) - \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \int_{t}^{t'} f(\Gamma(s)) \frac{\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)}{t' - t} \mathrm{d} s\right|  \\
    &\leq \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \left|\int_{t}^{t'} f(\gamma(t)) \frac{\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)}{t' - t} -  f(\Gamma(s)) \frac{\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)}{t' - t} \mathrm{d}  s\right|  \\
    &= \sum_{t \in \mathfrak{Z}} \frac{\left|\gamma(t') - \gamma(t)\right| }{t' - t} \left|\int_{t}^{t'} f(\gamma(t)) -  f(\Gamma(s)) \mathrm{d} s \right| \\
    &\leq \epsilon L(\gamma) \leq \epsilon K.
    \end{aligned}
$$

(3) Let us now finish the proof by describing the epsilontics. We want to show the convergence $\int_{\gamma_n} f(z) \mathrm{d} z \rightarrow \int_{\gamma_0} f(z)$, so let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Take a compact neighbourhood of $\gamma_0$ contained in $U$. In this region, $f$ is uniformly continuous, so take $\rho > 0$ so that $|z-w|<\rho$ implies $|f(z) - f(w)| < \epsilon$. Without loss of generality, the following happens in the neighbourhood of radius $\rho$ around $\gamma_0$. Further, $f$ will be bounded, say by $M$, and by Arzelà-Ascoli, $(\gamma_n)$ is uniformly equicontinuous, so there is $\alpha > 0$ so that if $|s-t| < \alpha$, then $|\gamma_n(s) - \gamma_n(t)| < \rho$ for all $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.

Now fix one finite subset $\mathfrak{Z} \subseteq [0, 1)$ with $0 \in \mathfrak{Z}$, such that $|\mathfrak{Z}| < \alpha$. It is crucial that for every purpose in the proof where such a set is needed, this fixed $\mathfrak{Z}$ is used. In particular, let $\Gamma_k$ be the polygonal approximation of $\gamma_k$ with base points from $\mathfrak{Z}$. Set $\beta = \min_{t} |\gamma_0(t') - \gamma_0(t)|$, $\delta :=\frac{1}{2} \min\{\rho, \epsilon \beta \}$ and finally $N$ so large that $|\gamma_0(t) - \gamma_n(t)| < \delta$ for all $n > N$ and $t \in [0, 1]$.

We have $$\left|\int_{\gamma_0} f - \int_{\gamma_n} f\right|
    \leq \left|\int_{\gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_0} f\right| + \left|\int_{\Gamma_0} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f\right| + \left|\int_{\gamma_n} f - \int_{\Gamma_n} f\right|.$$You can now go back to the calculations in (1) and (2) and verify that we have indeed chosen our constants correctly, so that the arguments go through. Thus the first and third summand are each at most $\epsilon (1 + 2 K)$ by (2), and the middle summand is at most $\epsilon L(\gamma_0) + \epsilon ML(\Gamma_0) \leq \epsilon (K + MK)$. So in all, $\left|\int_{\gamma_0} f - \int_{\gamma_n} f \right| \leq \epsilon (2 + 5 K + KM)$. As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this becomes as small as you want, QED.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to go over the details so I give here a sketch of a proof, which I'm fairly certain that is true, but not absolutely sure.

As I said in my comment, if you choose arc-length parameterization of the curves, I their derivatives converge uniformly too. Since the integral is independent of parameterization, you're done.

To see that you can choose such a parameterization, you should think of the arc length as defined by the supremum of piecewise-linear approximations, as in this image, taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length):

[image]

Doing that, you don't need to assume that the derivatives converge uniformly.

As I said above, I'm pretty sure this works, but I didn't write a formal proof so I might be missing something (probably related to fractal curves).