# Topology of "line integral convergence" on the space of curves

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, line-integrals

Let $C^1(I,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of $C^1$ curves. Give it the topology that satisfies that convergence of a sequence of curves $\gamma_n \to \gamma$ occurs iff these conditions hold:

> **a.** $\gamma_n(t) \to \gamma(t)$ pointwise for every $t \in I$.
>
> **b.** If $\omega$ is a $1$-form s.t. $\int_{\gamma} \omega$ is defined and $\int_{\gamma_n} \omega$ is defined
>       for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\int_{\gamma_n} \omega \to \int_{\gamma} \omega$.

**1. Is there a nice characterization of this topology in terms of modes of convergence?**

I know that a sufficient conditions for $\int_{\gamma_n} \omega \to \int_{\gamma} \omega$ to hold is pointwise convergence **and** uniform boundness of derivatives ($|\gamma_n| \le M$ for all $n$). Note: this convergence is stronger than uniform convergence.

**2. Is there an analogous treatment in the case of $n$-forms with convergence of hypersurfaces?**

Comment: So, what you're saying is of course the topology on $C^1(I)$ (assuming $I$ is compact) given by the usual $C^1$ norm. I believe you want the same thing for parametrized hypersurfaces ($(n-1)$-forms, by the way).

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you mean $||\gamma||=\sup |\gamma| + \sup |\gamma'|$ ? Is it an iff statement?

Comment: Yes, @Saal, that's the norm I meant. I've not thought about it before, but I would guess it's iff, yes. Try to write a proof.