# Does uniform convergence of curves imply convergence of integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma_n, \gamma: [0, 1] \to \mathbb C$ be (continuous) piecewise $C^1$ curves with $\gamma_n \to \gamma$ uniformly for $n \to \infty$ and $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ continuous. Does this already imply
$$
\int_{\gamma_n} f(z) \,\textrm{d}z \to \int_{\gamma} f(z) \,\textrm{d}z
$$
for $n \to \infty$?

Cauchy's integral theorem states this is true for holomorphic $f$, as then $\int_{\tilde \gamma} f(z) \,\textrm{d}z = 0$ for $\tilde \gamma = \gamma \oplus [\gamma(1), \gamma_n(1)] \oplus \gamma_n^- \oplus [\gamma_n(0), \gamma(0)]$.

However I wonder whether this is true for *any* continuous $f$. I *guess* “problematic“ curves could be something like
$$
\gamma_n(t) = t + i \cdot \frac1n \left[ \sin(n^2 \pi t) \right], \quad t \in [0, 1],
$$
as then $\|\gamma_n'\|_\infty$ is unbounded.

Comment: How do you define $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm dz$ for a continuous function $f$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos For $\gamma \in C^1([0, 1]; \mathbb C)$ we set $\int_\gamma f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z := \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Comment: So, you you wrote “ie. $\gamma_n$, $\gamma$ are continuous”, that's not what you meant.

Comment: I meant $C^0$, piecewise $C^1$ and *wanted* to clarify that curves are by definition continuous; that is, the “ie” only refers to “curves”. However, I agree that could lead to confusion and will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problematic curves do create problems. For $t\in [0,1],$ set

$$\gamma_n(t) = t +i\left (\frac{1}{n} + \frac{\sin(4^nt)}{2^n}\right).$$

Then for $n$ greater than some $n_0,$ the $\gamma_n$ are pairwise disjoint, compact, and converge uniformly to $\gamma(t) = t.$ Define $K= \gamma\cup (\cup_{n=1}^\infty\gamma_n).$ (Here I'm commiting the delightful crime of indentifying a contour with its range.) Then $K$ is compact.

Now define $f:K\to \mathbb C$ as follows: $f(\gamma_n(t)) = \cos(4^nt)/n, n=1,2,\dots,$ $f(\gamma (t)) = 0.$ Then $f$ is continuous on $K.$ By the Tietze extension theorem, $f$ extends to be continuous on all of $\mathbb C.$

I'll leave it to the reader to show $|\int_{\gamma_n} f(z)\, dz| \to \infty$ (fast), while $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\, dz=0.$ Thus we have a counterexample.